# Cpanel SQLite 3.8.3 or later is required (found 3.7.17)

Tags: python, django, cpanel

so i want to create a simple web page with django on Cpanel. 
I followed the tutorial right here : https://www.jvmhost.com/articles/django3-python3.7-cpanel/

But when i try to run the command : `./manage.py collectstatic` it gives me this error : `SQLite 3.8.3 or later is required (found 3.7.17).`

In the tutorial they say you need to modifiy the ~/.bashrc file and add this too lines :

`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH='/opt/atomicorp/atomic/root/usr/lib64/'
 export PATH=/opt/atomicorp/atomic/root/bin:$PATH`

I don't understand what these two lines do, but it don't change the problem and i still get the same error

What could i do to upgrade the sqlite in Cpanel ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to use Django on CPanel just use a version that is earlier than 3.0

Answer (score 0):

You have three option:

1. Downgrade you python version
2. Downgrade you django version
3. go to your virtual env site packages sqllite folder and open base.py
   and edit line 65 to "pass" instead of "raise ......."